# Number of linearly independent eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Can we determine if the following matrix has 3 linearly independent eigenvectors without any calculations? I know that it can be determined by calculating the eigenvalues, but I was wondering if something like that can be concluded just by observing this matrix, since it's a **true/false** question. Thanks

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 && 3 && 3 \\
-3 && -5 && -3 \\
3 && 3 && 1 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Note that the columns all add to the same number, that is, $1$.  That tells you immediately that $1$ is an eigenvalue.  This is really a follow up to @egreg answer.

Comment: @B.Goddard okay, so whenever I have a marix whose columns all add to the same number, I can automatically conclude that one eigenvalue is 1?

Comment: Not "1", but whatever they add to.  Because when you subtract $\lambda I$, you're subtracting $\lambda$ from the sum of each column, making the column sums of $A-\lambda I$ equal $0$, which means $A-\lambda I$ is singular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try $A+2I$, you get
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 3 & 3 \\
-3 & -3 & -3 \\
3 & 3 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which has rank $1$, so $-2$ is an eigenvalue with geometric multiplicity $2$.

Can you see another eigenvalue?

Comment: As @B.Goddard stated in their comment, it's 1. But the problem is that I need to conclude if the matrix has 3 linearly independent eigenvectors just by looking at it. I am no supposed to actually calculate them. Can it be done?

Comment: @ivana14 The first thing to look for is row sums and column sums. So immediately you get one eigenvalue is $1$. A simple look shows also that an eigenvalue is $-2$.

Comment: so whenever a matrix has a constant row sum **and** column sum, I can say that one eigenvalue is $1$? or either row or column sum can be constant? How did you get -2 just by looking at the matrix? Sorry, I am just really confused. thanks

Comment: @ivana14 No: if the columns have constant sum $s$, then $s$ is an eigenvalue; similarly if the rows have constant sum. For $-2$, I observed that adding $2$ to the diagonal gives a rank one matrix.

Comment: okay, but how am I allowed to add $2$ to the diagonal?

Comment: @ivana14 That's what you do with eigenvalues, isn't it?

Comment: okay, so, if I understand correctly, by adding $2$ to the diagonal we got a matrix whose $det$ is equal to $0$? so we know that $-2$ is definitely one eigenvalue.. Now what about the eigenvectors? How do we know if there are two linearly independent?

Comment: @ivana14 Not only the matrix $A+2I$ has zero determinant: it has rank $1$, so its null space has dimension $3-1=2$.

Comment: but how can I use that to determine the linear independency of eigenvectors?

Comment: @ivana14 That's very basic knowledge: the eigenspace of $A$ relative to $\lambda$ is the null space of $A-\lambda I$.

Comment: I know that, but the problem is that this is a true/false problem.. I am first supposed to say if the given matrix has 3 linear independent vectors, then explain my answer.. calculations are not allowed

Comment: @ivana14 Nullity of $A+2I$ equal to 2 means that the eigenspace of $-2$ is two dimensional, hence you can find two linearly independent eigenvectors of $-2$. Eigenvectors belonging to different eigenvalues are linearly independent. Show that the third eigenvalue isn’t also $-2$ (hint: examine the trace) and you’re done.